# Get CancellationToken delay value

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

I am writing some internal framework code and at some point I want to throw an `MyCustomException` when `TaskCanceledException` happens, because I want to add the delay configured for the `CancellationToken` to the message. That is, in:

```cs
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(cancellationTokenDelay);
return cancellationTokenSource.Token;
```

I want to get the value passed to the `CancelAfter` method. The problem is: `CancellationToken` does not seem to expose this information. Is there any trick to get it?

(I already considered timing the operation with a `Stopwatch`, but I am looking for a more elegant alternative).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all `CancellationToken`'s have a delay at all.  It's quite common to use them with a `CancellationTokenSource` that calls cancel based on something other than a set amount of time passing.

You'll either need to pass along that information with the Cancellation token to the task, or create your own subclass of `CancellationToken` that is only used in conjunction with a delay and that exposes that information publicly.

Comment: `CancellationToken` is a `struct`, so you can't subclass it.